$f$ non-constant in a region $G$, $f\equiv 7$ on $\partial G$, $f$ has $m$ zeros in $G$, how many zeros does $f'$ have in $G$?
Suppose that $f$ is a non-constant smooth function on $\mathbb{C}$, and that $\Gamma=\{z:|f(z)|=7\}$ is a smooth Jordan curve. Let $G$ be the bounded region enclosed by $\Gamma$. Suppose $f$ is analytic in $G$.
(a) Prove that $f$ has at least one zero in $G$.
(b) Assume further that $f'$ does not vanish on $\Gamma$, and that $f$ has $m\geq 1$ zeros in $G$ (counting multiplicity). How many zeros does $f'$ have in $G$?
Proof of (a):
If $f$ has no zeros in $G$, then $1/f$ is analytic in $G$. Since $1/|f|\equiv 1/7$ on $\Gamma$, but $1/|f|$ is not constant, the maximum principle implies that $1/|f|\leq 1/7$ on $\overline{G}$, or in other words, $|f|\geq 7$ on $\overline{G}$. But, since $|f|\equiv 7$ on $\partial G$, another application of the maximum principle implies $|f|\leq 7$ on $\overline{G}$. Hence, $f\equiv 7$ on $\overline{G}$, which is impossible as $f$ is non-constant.
We conclude that $f$ has at least one zero in $G$. $\blacksquare$
I am not sure how to conclude (b). My initial guess was to use the argument principle, since neither $f$ nor $f'$ vanishes on $\Gamma$. We get
$$ m=Z(f;G)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\Gamma}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\,\textrm{d}z,\qquad Z(f';G)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\Gamma}\frac{f''(z)}{f'(z)}\,\mathrm{d}z, $$
where $Z(g;U)$ denotes the number of zeros of $g$ in the open set $U$, counting multiplicity. I am not sure how to proceed.
We know that $f'$ has only finitely many zeros, as otherwise there would be a limit point of zeros of $f'$, and we conclude by identity theorem that $f'\equiv 0$, a contradiction. However, this doesn't give any further information on how many there are.

This was a past preliminary exam question, and edited to clear the confusion.

the answer is $m-1$ and one way to do it is to use RMT and move everything to the unit disc by a conformal isomorphism $\phi: \mathbb D \to G$ (which extends continuously as a homeomorphism from the closed unit disc to $G \cup \Gamma$) and note that the image $g= f\circ \phi$ is a constant multiple of a finite Blaschke product of degree $m$, while the zeroes of $f'$ (inside $G$) correspond to the zeroes of $g'$ (inside $\mathbb D$) since $\phi'$ doesn't vanish etc

@Conrad: Why don't you post that as an answer?

@Martin - ok expanded my comment in an answer though it may not be quite what the OP wants

This is a special case of the Riemann-Hurwitz formula, isn't it?

Expanding my comment above - one solution for point $b$ (which incidentally doesn't require any hypothesis on the derivative of $f$ but uses Caratheodory extension theorem which I am not sure is standard in an introductory complex analysis class) goes as follows.
By the Riemann Mappin Theorem there is a conformal isomorphism $\phi: \mathbb D \to G$ and by the Caratheodry extension theorem, $\phi$ extends to a homeomorphism from $\overline {\mathbb D} \to G \cup \Gamma$.
Let $g= f \circ \phi$ analytic on $\mathbb D$, continuous and of constant modulus $7$ on the unit circle (and with precisely $m$ zeroes inside the unit disc).
Then $g'=(f'\circ \phi) \phi'$ has the same number of zeroes inside the unit disc as $f'$ has in $G$ since $\phi'$ never vanishes inside the unit disc being a conformal isomorphism
(note that the above equation tells us nothing about what happens to the derivative of $f$ on $\Gamma$ since $\phi$ may not be analytic there etc).
But $g$ constant modulus $7$ with $m$ zeroes means $g=cB$ where $B$ is a finite Blaschke product with $m$ zeroes and $|c|=7$.
(standard proof by taking $B$ a Blaschke product with the same zeroes as those of $g$ and using that $g/B$ is analytic and doesn't vanish inside the unit disc and has constant modulus on the boundary so is constant).
Then it is a standard exercise (see below) to show that $B'$ hence $g'$ hence $f'$ has $m-1$ zeroes (including multiplicity of course) inside the unit disc.
The proof that $B'$ has $m-1$ zeroes inside the unit disc is done in two stages; first one assumes that $B$ has only single zeroes and the origin is not among them, while $B'$ also doesn't vanish at the origin.
Differentiating the relation $$B(z)\overline{B(1/\bar z)}=1, z \ne 0$$ and noting that $B(w) \ne 0$ implies $B(1/\bar w) \ne \infty$ we get that $w \ne 0$  is a zero of $B'$ iff $1/\bar w$ is also a zero of $B'$ and then computing $B'/B$ by logarithmic differentiation and simplifying the denominators we get that its zeroes which are the zeroes of $B'$ are also the zeroes of a polynomial of degree $2m-2$ hence pair in $m-1$ zeroes inside and $m-1$ outside the unit disc since by another computation one also shows that if $|z_k|<1, k=1,..m-1$ are the zeroes of $B$ $$e^{it}\frac{B'(e^{it})}{B(e^{it})}=\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}\frac{1-|z_k|^2}{|e^{it}-z_k|^2} >0$$ so $B'$ never has zeroes on the unit circle.
Then, in general, one shows that any $B$ of degree $m$ is locally uniformly approximated inside the unit disc by $B_k$ of degree $m$ and with simple zeroes not at the origin and also for which $B_k'(0) \ne 0$ and Hurwitz theorem shows that $B'$ also has $m-1$ zeroes inside the unit disc (though of course it may have less outside in this case)

We are going to want to work on the unit disc instead of $G$ because (a) it allows us to work with a particularly nice rational function  and (b) the unit disc is convex so we can extract a lot of information from Gauss-Lucas.
After applying Carathéodory extension / Schönflies and dividing by $7$ we can transform this problem into $F: \overline {\mathbb D} \longrightarrow \overline {\mathbb D}$ where $F$ is analytic on the interior and continuous on the boundary and $F\big(S^1 \big) \subseteq S^1$.  To simplify notation somewhat, we may assume WLOG that $F(0)\neq 0$.  $\Big[$If not, run the argument on $g:=F\circ m_\lambda$ with Möbius map $m_\lambda(z) = \frac{z-\lambda}{\overline \lambda \cdot z-1}$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb D$ such that $g(0)\neq 0$-- since $F$ has finitely many zeros in the unit disc almost any selection of $\lambda$ will work. $F$ and $g$ necessarily have the same number of zeros in the open disc and so do their first derivatives-- e.g. this is implied by the Argument Principle.$\Big]$  We in fact know that $F(z)$ is a rational function of the form $F(z) = \beta\cdot\frac{p(z)}{q(z)}$ for some $\beta \in S^1$ where $p(z)$ is degree $m$ with $m$ roots in $\mathbb D$ and $q(z)$ is its reciprocal polynomial, recalling that for $z\in S^1$ we have $\big \vert p(z)\big\vert = \big \vert q(z)\big\vert$.  Hence we may change the domain to $B\big(0,1+\delta\big)$ for small enough $\delta \gt 0$ and the co-domain to $\mathbb C$ and apply the Argument Principle in the usual way.
Define $\gamma:\big[0,1\big]\longrightarrow \mathbb C$ given by $\gamma(t)=\exp\big(2\pi i\cdot t\big)$
If the winding number $m=n\big(F\circ\gamma,0\big)=0$, then the Argument Principle tells us $F$ sends the interior of the unit disc into $\mathbb C- \mathbb D$ making $F$ constant per the maximum modulus principle but we know $F$ is non-constant so this is impossible $\big[$this was part (a)$\big]$. We know $0 \not \in F'\big(S^1\big)$ [see technical commentary at end] and $m=n\big(F\circ\gamma,0\big)\geq 1$, so
$n\Big(\big(F'(z)\big)\circ \gamma, 0\Big)=n\Big(\left(\frac{d}{dz}\frac{p(z)}{q(z)}\right)\circ \gamma, 0\Big)= n\Big(\big(\frac{p'(z)}{q(z)}-\frac{p(z)}{q(z)}\frac{q'(z)}{q(z)}\big)\circ \gamma, 0\Big) $
It remains to show $n\Big(\big(\frac{p'(z)}{q(z)}-\frac{p(z)}{q(z)}\frac{q'(z)}{q(z)}\big)\circ \gamma, 0\Big)=m-1 $.
For $\tau\in \big[0,1\big)$ define $R_\tau(z) := p(z) - \tau\cdot\alpha\cdot q(z)$ for some arbitrary $\alpha \in S^1$
$\implies  n\Big(R_\tau(z)\circ \gamma, 0\Big)=m\implies   n\Big(R_\tau'(z)\circ \gamma, 0\Big)=m-1$
where the first implication is Rouche and the second is Gauss-Lucas combined with the Argument Principle.  Since $0\not \in R'_\tau\big(S^1\big)$ and the choice of $\alpha$ was arbitrary we conclude that for $z\in S^1$
$\Big\vert p'(z)\Big\vert \gt \Big\vert \tau \cdot q'(z)\Big\vert \implies \Big\vert \frac{p'(z)}{q(z)}\Big\vert \gt \Big\vert \tau \cdot\frac{q'(z)}{q(z)}\Big\vert =  \Big\vert \tau \cdot\frac{p(z)}{q(z)}\frac{q'(z)}{q(z)}\Big\vert$ which implies
$ m-1 = n\Big(\left(\frac{p'(z)}{q(z)}\right)\circ \gamma, 0\Big)   =  n\Big(\left(\frac{p'(z)}{q(z)}-\tau^*\cdot\frac{p(z)}{q(z)}\frac{q'(z)}{q(z)}\right)\circ \gamma, 0\Big) =  n\Big(\left(\frac{p'(z)}{q(z)}-\frac{p(z)}{q(z)}\frac{q'(z)}{q(z)}\right)\circ \gamma, 0\Big)$
where $n\Big(\big(p'(z)\big)\circ \gamma, 0\Big) = m-1$ per Gauss-Lucas combined with the Argument Principle and $\tau^*\in \big(1-\delta^*,1\big)$, for any $\delta^*\gt 0$ small enough implies the right hand side holds by Rouche, and of course the middle equality holds by Rouche.
technical commentary:
The general Carathéodory extension / Schönflies problem for a Jordan curve does not imply the homeomorphism (which is analytic on the interior) is necessarily differentiable on the boundary.  The expedient work around, and probably what was intended since (b) tells us that $f'$ does not vanish on $\Gamma$, is to import the specialized theory for smooth Jordan curves which tells us the extension to the boundary given by a smooth Jordan Curve is itself smooth.  Then $h(z):=7\cdot F(z)$ and $\sigma$ is simple curve on $S^1$ with $\sigma = \phi\circ \Gamma$, we have $ h\circ \sigma = \big(f \circ \phi\big)\circ\sigma = f \circ \big(\phi\circ\sigma\big) = f \circ \Gamma$.  Knowing that $f'$ does not vanish on $\Gamma$ and $\Gamma$ is injective and smooth, we can apply the chain rule to see the right hand side is never zero, hence applying the chain rule to the left hand side tells us $F'(z)\neq 0$ for $\vert z \vert =1$.
Alternatively, just using typical Schönflies, we can bypasses the behavior of $f'$ on $\Gamma$ by observing that when $F(z)$ is constrained to the unit disc, $\big \vert F(z)\big \vert\leq 1$ and the inequality is met with equality iff $\vert z\vert =1$ per max modulus theorem . This tells us that $F(z)$ has non-zero derivative on $S^1$, ref e.g. $f: \Omega \to \mathbb{C}$ is analytic and satisfies $|f(z)| \leq|f(1)|$ whenever $|z|<1$ ; note we may always consider $F_\alpha\big(z\big) := F\big(\alpha \cdot z\big)$ for arbitrary $\alpha \in S^1$ hence this holds for arbitrary points on the unit circle, not just $1$.

for reciprocal polynomial $q(z)$ ref e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4941110/proving-existence-of-a-root-in-the-unit-disk-using-rouch%c3%a9s-theorem/4941351#4941351 .  $\frac{p(z)}{q(z)}$ is more typically referred to as a finite Blaschke product though the idea for considering $R_\tau(z) := p(z) - \tau\cdot\alpha\cdot q(z)$ came from first looking at the Schur Transform of $p(z)$.
